# Only run supervisor restart if the process is not already running?

Tags: supervisord

I have a regular cron entry to restart a supervisor process, in case my site has gone down:

```
01 12 * * * /usr/bin/supervisorctl restart {instance name}
```

But is there a way I can only restart if the site has actually gone down, i.e. if the instance is not running?

Alternatively, is there a way I can do a graceful restart?

Comment: I guess I can just do `supervisorctl start {instance name}` and that will just produce an error if the app is already running, which is hopefully harmless... but I don't know if there's a non-error-producing way?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: **supervisorctl start** will fail pretty badly if supervisor is already running